# Using Category Thumbnails as link

Tags: category, thumbnail, link

Is it possible to use the sub-category thumbnails as a link to the category? So that you can click the thumbnail instead of the text, if yes, can you then also remove the text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a static block with the code: `subcategories` and insert:

```
{{block type="core/template" template="catalog/category/sub.phtml"}}
```

Create `catalog/category/sub.phtml`

```
<?php
$category = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer')->getCurrentCategory();
$categories = $category->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'thumbnail'))
        ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1)
        ->addUrlRewriteToResult()
        ->addIdFilter($category->getChildren())
?>
<ul class="subcategories">
    <?php foreach ($categories as $category): ?>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php echo $category->getUrl() ?>"><img src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl('media') . 'catalog' . DS . 'category' . DS . $category->getThumbnail() ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($category->getName()) ?>" />
                <span><?php echo $category->getName() ?></span></a>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Now assign and set whatever root category you want to show its sub categories as their thumbnails with the assigned `subcategories` CMS Block created.  Make sure Display mode is set to either Static block only or Products and Static block.

Source:

- http://www.creare.co.uk/magento-subcategories-category-pages

In order to resize the category icons/thumbnails you'll need this:

**Resize Category Images**:

- https://github.com/dbashyal/Magento-resize-category-images

With the above installed the change to make is:

```
<?php //echo Mage::getBaseUrl('media') . 'catalog' . DS . 'category' . DS . $category->getThumbnail() ?>
<img src="<?php echo $this->helper('timage')->init(Mage::getBaseUrl('media') . 'catalog' . DS . 'category' . DS . $category->getThumbnail())->resize(null, 140) ?>" width="140" height="140" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($category->getName()) ?>" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.
first get the category collection.
in that collection give same anchor tag to thumb also which is given to it's title.