# Return sub category thumbnails on all pages (at all levels)

Tags: magento-1.7, category

I have the following to return all thumbnails however it only returns top-level category thumbnails:

```
                        <?php $_helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category'); ?>
                        <?php $_categories = $_helper->getStoreCategories(false, true, false)
                                        ->addAttributeToSelect('thumbnail')                    
                                        ->addOrderField('name');?>

                        <ul class="categories-slider-list">
                         <?php foreach($_categories as $_category): ?>
                         <?php $thumb = Mage::getBaseUrl('media').'catalog/category/'.$_category->getThumbnail();?>
                          <div>
                           <a href="<?php echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl($_category) ?>"><?php echo '<div><img src="'.$thumb.'" /></div>';?></a>
                          </div>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                        </ul>
```

Comment: Possible related: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/44331/using-category-thumbnails-as-link/44341#44341

Comment: Thanks I did try this earlier but it only returned the root-level category for me whereas I need to show the entire list of category thumbnails at all levels.

Comment: I have found the solution for myself - here's the code:

`<?php
$categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
->getCollection()
->addAttributeToSelect('*')
->addIsActiveFilter()
->addAttributeToFilter('level',4)
->addOrderField('name');
foreach($categories as $category):
?><div><a href="<?php echo $category->getURL() ?>"><img src="http://kaisertech.wecreatedigit.al/media/catalog/category/<?php echo $category->getThumbnail() ?>" width="140" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($category->getName()) ?>"></a></div>
<?php endforeach; ?>`